# What is wrong with my solution - SPOJ - ALTSEQ?

Tags: c++

**What I need to do:** I need to solve [[ this ]](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ALTSEQ/) problem on SPOJ.

Given an array a of N integers a1, a2, a3, ... aN I have to find the length of the longest alternating subsequence of the array.
An alternating sequence b1, b2 ... bk, k>=1 is a sequence that has the 2 following properties:

1. |b1|<|b2|<|b3|<.....<|bk|
2. The signs alternate between adjacent elements, i.e, if b1 > 0 then b2<0, b3 >0 and so on. Alternatively, if b1<0, then b2>0, b3<0 and so on.

**My approach:**
The problem is a variation of the *Longest Increasing Subsequence* (LIS) problem. And here is my memoization based recursive solution:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

long *a;
int *dp;

int solve(int);
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a = new long[n];
    dp = new int[n]{};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%ld", a+i);
    printf("%d", solve(n-1));
}

int solve(int n)
{
    if (dp[n]) return dp[n];
    int &m = dp[n] = 1, k;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if (((a[n] < 0 && a[j] > 0 && -a[n] > a[j]) || (a[n] > 0 && a[j] < 0 && a[n] > -a[j])))
            if ((k = 1 + solve(j)) > m) m = k;
    return m;
}
```

**My Question:** This solution gives wrong answer on the judge system so there must be something wrong with it. I need help to figure out what is wrong with this solution since I can't on my own.

Comment: What did you try to test it?

Comment: (3 1 -2 -3 5 -7 -8 10)-->5 ; (1 -2 -3 3 4 5 6 -7) --> 4;  (1 2) -->1; (1 -2) --> 2 ; (-2 1 3 -2 3)-->3; (-2 4 3 -2 -4)-->3; (-4 4 3 -2 -4)-->2 and many more. All are correct.

Comment: Your entire problem statement is "This solution gives wrong answer" ?

Comment: What are the messages returned by SPOJ?  Timeout?  Seg_fault?  Incorrect answer?

Comment: So you really need recursion?  Does SPOJ run out of memory for the recursion?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: As I mentioned it gives wrong answer. And even if it did run out of recursion memory, it would have given an error message other than "wrong answer". And no, I suppose recursion is not necessary.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit: Yes. And I need to find out why it is so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred to me later that solve(i) is calculating dp[i] which is the LIS ending with the ith element. The maximum of the whole dp array therefore, is the correct answer not dp[n-1] which I was printing before.

Also, the recursive solution can be converted to bottom-up for efficiency. Furthermore, in bottom-up, the outer one of the two loops involved can be combined with the input reading loop and maximum dp[i] can be kept track of within the outer loop itself to avoid another pass to find maximum. This should result in a faster solution.

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, k, m = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    long *a = new long[n];
    int *dp = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%ld", a+i);
        dp[i] = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (((a[i] < 0 && a[j] > 0 && -a[i] > a[j]) || (a[i] > 0 && a[j] < 0 && a[i] > -a[j])) && (k = 1 + dp[j]) > dp[i]) dp[i] = k;
        if (dp[i] > m) m = dp[i];
    }
    printf("%d\n", m);
}
```